# Software that lets me type a few letters in order to search through the names of the files in the current directory

Tags: windows, gratis, file-management, search

In Windows Explorer, there's a search box that searches the files.  But it's slow, and its searches recurse into subfolders.  I'd like something that filters the files quickly, without recursing into subdirectories.

At a minimum, it should work in Windows Explorer.  If it also works in Open File dialog boxes in other applications, even better.

I don't want to pay for this; I'm looking for freeware.

Comment: Your question was poorly worded and hard to understand.  I first thought of putting it into the question closure queue.  Luckily for you, I figured out what you meant and decided to [edit] the question instead.  Please put more effort into your posts in the future.  Please focus on spelling, grammar, and clarity.  You will get more upvotes, your questions will have a higher likelihood of being tweeted, and your questions will likely get more attention.

Comment: Did you know that, in Windows Explorer, you can often select the file you want by typing the first few letters of its filename?

Comment: If you are not married to Windows Explorer, then (IMO superior) tools like Total Commander do what you want (and a whole lot  more that WE does not), so quickly as to seem instantaneous http://ghisler.com/